# Casting Json to Generic List

Tags: c#, json, generics

I have a json file like

```
var json=[{
"ControlId":2,
"PageNumber":2,
"Top":"11",
"Left":"11",
"Height":50,
"Width":50  
}]
```

and I have a entity class named DocumentControl is like

```
public class DocumentControlWI
    {

        public int ControlId { get; set; }        
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }        
        public string Top { get; set; }        
        public string Left { get; set; }        
        public int Height { get; set; }        
        public int Width { get; set; }        

}
```

how can I cast the json file to Generic collection of my entity.I am using newtonsoft for desalinizing json. Thanks in advance for help?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentControlWI[]>(json);`

Answer (score 3):

Using json.net:

```
var jsonStr = "[{\"ControlId\":2,\"PageNumber\":2,\"Top\":\"11\",\"Left\":\"11\",\"Height\":50,\"Width\":50}]";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DocumentControlWI>>(jsonStr);
```

1.jsonStr must be a string json.
2.Since you have a json array, you would like to convert it into a collection.

Comment: Your answer uses a JSON string modified to fit the answer you want to give, rather than trying to figure out what's wrong. The "real" answer is for Arun to update his question with details about what he's tried and why that doesn't work.

Comment: @AndyJ - Two things are wrong on his end. 1. The json var must be a string and it seems like he copied some js code and I just showed him how to make it work correctly.
2. Since his json is a array he will need to deserialize it into a collection.

BTW, his json is 100% valid.

Comment: Sorry,  I tried to add "@user" in a comment edit, but it wouldn't let me so I've deleted that comment and reposted it correctly ... The "JSON file" starts with "var json=", that's 100% invalid.

Comment: @AndyJ - Everybody understood what he meant here except you. Downvoting other peoples answers is a positive thing to do when the answer is wrong.

Comment: Fair enough ... I shall move on.